# How to plot multiple values of each country on worldmap with Highchart for R

Tags: r, highcharts

I have a data of co2 emissions as below and am pasting a sample of it:

```
test_data<-structure(
  list(
    name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"),
    total = c(217.993073, 293.838988, 4862.566823),
    coal = c(57.676473,
             66.78178, 117.54147),
    oil = c(131.577257, 185.838389, 1653.701878),
    gas = c(20.266629, 16.707287, 2154.349422),
    cement = c(2.516676,
               24.375176, 243.216837),
    flaring = c(5.956043, 0.136357, 693.757211),
    other = c(0, 0, 0),
    coal_percent = c(26.46, 22.73, 2.42),
    oil_percent = c(60.36, 63.24, 34.01),
    gas_percent = c(9.3,
                    5.69, 44.3),
    cement_percent = c(1.15, 8.3, 5),
    flaring_percent = c(2.73,
                        0.05, 14.27),
    other_percent = c(0, 0, 0)
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-3L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria"),
      .rows = structure(
        list(1L, 2L, 3L),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-3L),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)
```

I am trying to show each emission's percent for each country on worldmap with highchart for R.

I tried:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=all_emissions_percent, value="coal_percent",
                    name="Coal Emissions", joinBy = "name") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=all_emissions_percent, value="oil_percent",
                    name="Oil Emissions", joinBy = "name") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=all_emissions_percent, value="gas_percent",
                    name="Gas Emissions", joinBy = "name") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=all_emissions_percent, value="cement_percent",
                    name="Cement Emissions", joinBy = "name") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=all_emissions_percent, value="flaring_percent",
                    name="Flaring Emissions", joinBy = "name") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df=all_emissions_percent, value="other_percent",
                    name="Other Emissions", joinBy = "name") %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(stops=stops) %>% 
  hc_title(text="Total  Emissions")
```

The world map is showing the last emission value only i.e., other emissions. Is there any other way to plot all values for individual countries and show as the below examples:

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p7u9xL3q/)

Comment: You can format this data in highcharts.tooltip.formatter by wrapping this in a js function. Below you can find a simplified example of how to do it and display this data as you want: library(highcharter)

x <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun")
y <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "line") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = x) %>%
  hc_series(list(name = "Sales", data = y)) %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    formatter = JS(
      "function() {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + 'Sales: ' + this.y;
      }"
    )
  )

Comment: @madepiet thank you for the tip but am looking for a world map plot. I tried to your code (with some changes) to make it apply for world map, but am not getting what I needed. Can you please give a code for world map?

Comment: @madepiet Figured it out. Check the code below and thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. First I need to create a new column with all percentages separated by line break '

```
test_data <- test_data %>%
  mutate(percentages = paste0("Coal: ", round(coal_percent, 2), "%", "<br>",
                              "Oil: ", round(oil_percent, 2), "%", "<br>",
                              "Gas: ", round(gas_percent, 2), "%", "<br>",
                              "Cement: ", round(cement_percent, 2), "%", "<br>",
                              "Flaring: ", round(flaring_percent, 2), "%", "<br>",
                              "Other: ", round(other_percent, 2), "%"))
```

Then plot this new column on world map using highcharts

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, df = test_data, value = "percentages", 
                    name="All Emissions Percentage",joinBy = "name") %>%
  hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = list(
    list(from = 0, to = 5, color = "#74c476"),
    list(from = 5, to = 10, color = "#1e2761"),
    list(from = 10, to = 20, color = "#fdae6b"),
    list(from = 20, to = 30, color = "#7a2048"),
    list(from = 30, to = 40, color = "#e6550d"),
    list(from = 40, to = 50, color = "#a63603"),
    list(from = 50, to = 100, color = "#FF0000")
  )) %>%
  hc_title(text = "All Emissions") %>%
  hc_tooltip(
    useHTML = TRUE,
    formatter = JS(
      "function() {
        var s = '<b><span style=\"font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;\">' + this.point.name + '</span></b><br/>';
        var values = this.point.value.split('<br>');
        $.each(values, function(i, value) {
          var color;
          var percent = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
          if (percent <= 5) {
            color = '#74c476';
          } else if (percent <= 10) {
            color = '#1e2761';
          } else if (percent <= 20) {
            color = '#fdae6b';
          } else if (percent <= 30) {
            color = '#7a2048';
          } else if (percent <= 40) {
            color = '#e6550d';
          } else if (percent <= 50) {
            color = '#a63603';
          } else {
            color = '#FF0000';
          }
          s += '<span style=\"color: ' + color + '; font-weight: bold;\">' + value + '</span><br/>';
        });
        return s;
      }"
    )
  )
```

Note that the color_axis and hc_tooltip formatter are completely optional. I have customized it for aesthetic appearance:

[image: test_plot]